# React, delay render and hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and I have weird situation, it's simple in theory but I don't know how to solve it. At first I'm using `props.children` and I want to render some part of the code when I get the response. I'm kind of solve it in a strange way but I still have errors. So have a look:

```
function AddCards(axiosResponse) {

  const [cardsCode, setCardsCode] = React.useState(null);

  const handleGetCards = (newCode) => {
    setCardsCode(newCode);
  };

  var firstText = null;
  var cards = axiosResponse;
  if (cards[0]) {
    firstText = [];
    firstText.push( <div>
      <h1>{cards[0].title}</h1>
      <p>{cards[0].text}</p></div>
    );
    handleGetCards(firstText);
  }

  return (
    <ButtonAppBar>
      {cardsCode}
    </ButtonAppBar>
  );
}

function makeRequest() {
  axiosCall(AddCards);
}

makeRequest();

ReactDOM.render(<AddCards />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

The thing I wanted to do is to get the response from `axiosCall()` which returns an array of dicts and use it in the `AddCards` function. I had a lot of errors and to avoid it I used function `makeRequest` which calls `axiosCall` which calls `AddCards` as a callback (maybe someone knows better solution because that one is horrible I think). But ok, now I'm trying to make it work, I created state so react should re-render when it changed and I made it null by default. And `if (cards[0])` checks if response came and it should change the state. But I have an error `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call`. What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Where are you learning React? You have a few fairly significant issues. Maybe start from the official documentation?

Comment: Seconded. You need to take a quick step back—while I think I understand what you thought you were doing it’s only because I have a vivid imagination. Please consider spinning through any React tutorial that has an Ajax call in it—you’ll find significant differences in structure, but not so many you can’t translate it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you pass the request response as a `prop` to your component:

```
function AddCards(props) {
  const response = props.response;
  // do stuff with data here
}

function makeRequest() {
  // some further logic here
  axiosCall();
}

makeRequest().then((response) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<AddCards response={response}/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
});
```

Or you use the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function AddCards() {
  const [cardsCode, setCardsCode] = React.useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    makeRequest().then((response) => {
      // extract data from response based on your need
      setCardsCode(response);
    });
  }, []);

  // access cardsCode in your function
}


makeRequest().then((response) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<AddCards/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, now I know a little bit more. Can I ask you one more question? I solved it a little bit different, with promises. You use `.then` in your answer, is there supposed to be promises and you just didn't mention it as obvious?

Comment: You call `.then()` on a Promise. Are you talking about `async`/`await`? If you are using a modern enough version of js it works of course (and it is more readable).